# Wine damage on MacBook Air 13'3 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, logicboard

As the title gives away I spilled a glass of wine on my mac. I turned it head down right a way and dried it. Every thing seemed to work fine until half an hour later i put it in charge. It first kept disconnecting from charge and then it wouldn't charge anymore. So I opened it up and there seems to be some kind of stain near the thunderbolt ports on the logic board the rest of it seems to be fine and there also a blinking light.
This is the stain picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlGz1.jpg
This is the LED that is still on:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnjXB.jpg

Will it be necessary to change the whole logic board? I am considering sending it to an apple certified repair shop. I am just looking to walk in prepared as to not get robbed as I am a student and can't really afford a $700 new logic board. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Hardware issues are notoriously difficult to troubleshoot in this forum.  Your best best is to take it to a certified repair shop for estimates.

Comment: My son spilt beer in his macbook pro - completely trashed it and it was replaced under insurance after inspection.

Comment: Whatever initial damage the wine did was exacerbated by turning it over, then plugging it back in. Expect it to need a new logic board - they don't repair at component level any more, just change the whole board (& often top-case too). Check to see if your insurance covers it.